# Is this an IE 8 and 9 quirk related to window object or variable hoisting?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that works fine in recent versions of FireFox (at least since version 34) and Chrome, and IE 10.

IE 8 and 9 are barking at me however and I don't know if it's how I coded this or something to do with non-standard javascript and/or DOM implementations on the latter two browsers.

Essentially I'm setting a property on the `window` object in the `document.ready` event, and I'm not seeing it later on in IE8 and 9.
Small psuedocode snippet showing the problem:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var myVariable = "hello";
   window.myVariable = myVariable;
   callMyMethod();
});

function callMyMethod() {
  console.log(window.myVariable); //undefined in IE8 and 9, fine elsewhere
};
```

My actual code is a bit more complicated than the above (I realize that's a dangerous statement) but given the above is there something about IE8 and 9 that sticks out as to why this sort of code wouldn't work; possible hoisting or other thing?

Comment: Are you actually using mVariable as your variable name? or are you using something else that may be reserved or used in 8 and 9.

Comment: Are they contained within the same `<script>` block?  I just found [this comment](http://tobyho.com/2013/03/13/window-prop-vs-global-var/#comment-830081810) on a blog post, leading to [this snippet](http://jsbin.com/uxetod/12/edit?html,output) which may imply the same behaviour you're seeing, assuming you have multiple `<script>` blocks

Comment: Can you show which name is given to that `window` property? It might be relevant.

Comment: @JamesThorpe you are correct, they are in separate script blocks-- thanks for that link

Comment: @raina77ow the actual property name is 'window._kiq', so I don't think(?) it's reserved in some way.